# :app:transform Classes With Profilers-transform For Debug FAILED

Tags: profiler

The following error occurred while opening Android Profiler compilation：
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithProfilers-transformForDebug'.

Answer (score 107):

[image]

Disable this switch will fix your problem.

1. Select Run > Edit Configurations.
2. Select your app module in the left pane.
3. Click the Profiling tab, and then check to disable advanced profiling.

Comment: Worked for me. If you ask yourself where to find that dialog like I did: it is "Edit configurations".  Help=>Find Action or click the button with "app" near the run button.

Comment: This worked for me. I am not sure how this got enabled. :)

Comment: So what's the reason?

Comment: This is not fix, this is workaround. In my case I must have it enabled.

Comment: @Michalsx I am facing the same issue. Did you get it fixed?

Comment: @ChaturaM Unfortunately, no, I did not find any solution with enabled advanced profiling.

Comment: @Michalsx Thanks for your response. I did little bit further digging and found out it is caused by a JAR file added to the project.

Comment: @ChaturaM So then how did you fix it?

Comment: @DevAndroid I didn't

Comment: @michalsx I also need it and all of these solutions just tell us how to disable it. Although, I've read on a blog that you've to enable advanced analytics as well with this to use. But, I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

For me, cleaning the project and building again fixed it.